# Send multipart file without filename

Tags: karate

I would like to send a multipart file **without a filename** using Karate DSL but some mechanism within Karate DSL automatically sets a filename

**Feature #1**

```
Feature: Send file without filename

Background:
* url 'http://localhost'
* configure proxy = 'http://localhost:8080'
* configure ssl = { "trustAll": true }

Scenario:
    Given path '/upload'
    And multipart field REQUEST = 'Hello world'
    And header Content-Type = 'multipart/form-data'
    And multipart file myfile.bin = { value: 'Hello world from file', contentType: application/octet-stream }
    When method POST
    Then status 200
```

Setting no or even an empty filename attribute still results in

> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="myfile.bin"; filename="myfile.bin"

**Feature #2**

```
Feature: Send file without filename

Background:
* url 'http://localhost'
* configure proxy = 'http://localhost:8080'
* configure ssl = { "trustAll": true }

Scenario:
    Given path '/upload'
    And multipart field REQUEST = 'Hello world'
    And header Content-Type = 'multipart/form-data'
    And multipart file myfile.bin = { value: 'Hello world from file', contentType: application/octet-stream, filename: '' }
    When method POST
    Then status 200
```

**Feature #3**

```
Feature: Send file without filename

Background:
* url 'http://localhost'
* configure proxy = 'http://localhost:8080'
* configure ssl = { "trustAll": true }

Scenario:
    Given path '/upload'
    And multipart field REQUEST = 'Hello world'
    And header Content-Type = 'multipart/form-data'
    And multipart file myfile.bin = { value: 'Hello world from file', contentType: application/octet-stream, filename: '#(null)' }
    When method POST
    Then status 200
```

**Responses captured with mitmproxweb**

Feature #1: [Screenshot from mitmproxweb (without specifying a filename)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j28E6.png)

Feature #2: [Screenshot from mitmproxweb (specifying an empty filename)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6FT2.png)

Feature #3: [Screenshot from mitmproxweb (specifying null as filename)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKcFK.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`multipart entity`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#multipart-entity) - that is designed to not set a name.

Finally if that does not work, you can resort to building the raw payload as described here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/921#issuecomment-544161221 - but do consider contributing a fix (or an [example](https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue) that helps us fix).